# Using ip6tables with range

Tags: ip6tables

I'm trying to ban an ip range with ip6tables.

I'm adding this line to /etc/sysconfig/ip6tables

```
-A INPUT -s ::ffff:58.26.318.213 -j DROP
```

But I want to ban everything that starts with 58.26 so that it bans ::ffff:58.26.318.214 and ::ffff:58.26.318.215 as well. How do I do it? THanks.

Comment: That's an IPv4 address, it doesn't belong in ip6tables!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Doesn't the ::ffff: indicate ipv6?

Comment: Do you mean CIDR notation, e.g. `::ffff:58.26.318.213/112`? Why do you have a 318 in the decimal part?